# Defining external function (module) in the header file in C

Tags: c, struct, header, extern

When I compile the program, outlined below, I am getting the following error(s) back

```
[igor@localhost ~/I2C]$ make i2c_VIPER DEFINE=-DVIPER
gcc -g -Wall -D__USE_FIXED_PROTOTYPES__ -DVIPER -ansi -lusb   -c -o i2c.o i2c.c
In file included from i2c.c:9:
viperboard.h:120: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
i2c.c: In function ‘main’:
i2c.c:32: error: ‘usb_dev’ undeclared (first use in this function)
i2c.c:32: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
i2c.c:32: error: for each function it appears in.)
i2c.c:33: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘i2c_VIPER’
make: *** [i2c.o] Error 1
```

I've tried many things,  more or less semi-blindly,  to make it working. The `struct parsed_CLI_I2C_t` defined by me, works flawlessly. No compilation errors. But, when I try to use `struct usb_device` from `<usb.h>` in equivalent way, the compiler is not happy. 
What I am doing wrong ?

Relatively detailed description follows.

Let's start with a code snippet from the standard `#include` < [usb.h](http://www.libusb.org/browser/libusb-compat-0.1/libusb/usb.h/) > <-- link to the full header file

```
/* Data types */
struct usb_device;
struct usb_bus;

struct usb_device {
  struct usb_device *next, *prev;

  char filename[PATH_MAX + 1];

  struct usb_bus *bus;

  struct usb_device_descriptor descriptor;
  struct usb_config_descriptor *config;

  void *dev;        /* Darwin support */

  u_int8_t devnum;

  unsigned char num_children;
  struct usb_device **children;
};
```

Here is the first local header file #include "viperboard.h"

```
struct parsed_CLI_I2C_t;
extern int  i2c_VIPER (struct usb_device **usb_dev, struct parsed_CLI_I2C_t **CLI_I2C_options);
extern bool OpenDevice(void);
```

This is the second local header file  #include "I2C.h"

```
typedef struct 
{
   char  *USB_board; 
   int    query;
   int    write_type;
} parsed_CLI_I2C_t;

extern int  parse_CLI_I2C_options (int argc, char *argv[], parsed_CLI_I2C_t **CLI_I2C_options);
```

The main program looks like this

```
/* all other standard include stuff skipped for brevity */
#include <usb.h>
#include "viperboard.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "I2C.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   parsed_CLI_I2C_t *CLI_I2C_options;
   parse_CLI_I2C_options (argc, argv, &CLI_I2C_options);

   struct usb_device *usb_dev; 
   i2c_VIPER (&usb_dev, &CLI_I2C_options);
}
```

and, finally, this is the external module

> i2c_VIPER.c

```
/* all other standard include stuff skipped for brevity */
#include <usb.h>
#include "viperboard.h"     
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "I2C.h"

int  i2c_VIPER (struct usb_device **usb_dev, struct parsed_CLI_I2C_t **CLI_I2C_options )
{
   bool   connected;         /* True if the ViperBoard is connected */

   connected = OpenDevice();

   return(0);
}
```

This is

> OpenDevice.c

```
 #include <stdbool.h>
 #include <usb.h>

 bool OpenDevice()  /* <----  this is line 11 */ 
 {
     usb_set_debug( 0 );

     /* Initialize USB library */
     usb_init( );

     etc etc etc 

     return true;
 }
```

========================================================
30 minutes later: all suggested changes implemented
Another type of error appeared.

```
 OpenDevice.c:11: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘OpenDevice’
make: *** [OpenDevice.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
usb_device *usb_dev;  /* this is line 32 */
```

will not work as you're compiling a C program, not a C++ program. In C structures are not automatically types like they are in C++. You need to use the `struct` keyword to declare structures:

```
struct usb_device *usb_dev;  /* this is line 32 */
```

This change you have to do for every place where you use structures, for example like the declaration and definition of the `i2c_VIPER` function.

Also note that for the `bool` type to work, you need to include `<stdbool.h>`.

Comment: Well and fast spotted. If the struct is to be used at more than a few places, I generally make a typedef of it: `typedef struct usb_device usb_device_t`. It often looks cleaner, IMO.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I've implemented it in the initial post, hopefully, ALL suggested changes. Unfortunately, another error appeared. `OpenDevice.c:11: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘OpenDevice’
make: *** [OpenDevice.o] Error 1`
Please see the bottom of the original post.

Comment: @Igor And you do include `<stdbool.h>` to get the `bool` type?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg.  Yes, in all of them except one. OpenDevice.c did not have it.